# Can you configure ElasticBeanstalk Loadbalanced SSL cert via the .ebexensions file?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have an AWS ElasticBeanstalk application. There are various environments, some load balanced some not.

At the moment with the load balanced ones, the SSL is configured manually in the console, whereas the single instance ones are configured via the `.ebextensions` file (and only for the single instance deployments).

Is there a way to configure the SSL for load balancers via the `.ebextensions` file as well, so we can keep it all in one place, and automate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not tried this yet, but while reading the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html), I've discover that it is possible to automate it.
If you have any lucky on following the instructions in the documentation, please let me know.

Update:

I actually tested, and yes, it is possible. Here follow a configuration example:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
    option_name: ListenerProtocol
    value: HTTPS

  - namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
    option_name: InstancePort
    value: 80

  - namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
    option_name: InstanceProtocol
    value: HTTP

  - namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
    option_name: SSLCertificateId
    value: arn:aws:iam::<your arn cert id here>

  - namespace: aws:elb:listener:80
    option_name: ListenerEnabled
    value: true

  - namespace: aws:elb:listener:443
    option_name: ListenerEnabled
    value: true
```